# iOS 8.3: hidden table row is still visible in the background

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

In order to hide a table row in some situations I set its height to 0. It works great but unfortunately I still see the row in the background. Can anybody explain this to me? How am I supposed to solve this? I believe I could switch the cell background color from Default (transparent) to something else but in some cases I might want to get the color from the table view itself (from the background)...

Comment: `[... setClipsToBounds:TRUE];` or `....clipsToBounds = true`, perhaps... but I would not show those cells which would not appear anyway because their height is `0`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll check and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell is render beyond the bounds of the cell, you will need to clip the subviews.

Either in Interface Builder thick the clip subviews box of set the `clipsToBounds` to `YES`.